# Remove $x$ from the term

Tags: trigonometry

We have to prove the below identity.

$$\mbox{arcsec}(x/a) - \mbox{arcsec}(x/b) = \mbox{arcsec }b - \mbox{arcsec }a$$

Given that $a$ ,$b$ are not equal and both are greater than $1$. 
I started from $LHS$ and transformed arcsec into $arctan$ and then add them.

But not able to remove $x$ from the term.

Comment: What is the definition of $\text{arcsec}(\cdot)$?

Comment: Take the secant of both members.

Comment: After that @YvesDaoust

Comment: Use trigonometric identitites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

By observation, one of the possible solution(s) is $ab$

Start with $\sec^{-1}u=\cos^{-1}\dfrac1u$

and $\cos^{-1}\dfrac ax+\cos^{-1}\dfrac1a=\cos^{-1}\dfrac1b+\cos^{-1}\dfrac bx$

Now apply $\cos(A+B)$ formula on both sides using

if $\cos^{-1}p=u,\ \cos u=p,0\le u\le\pi;\sin u=+\sqrt{1-p^2}$

Then square both sides to find $$x^2=(ab)^2$$

What if $x=-ab?$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\sec{(\alpha-\beta)}=\frac{\sec{\alpha}\sec\beta}{1+\tan\alpha\tan\beta}=\frac{\sec{\alpha}\sec\beta}{1+(\sec\alpha\sec\beta)(\sin\alpha\sin\beta)}$$
And note that
$$\cos(\sec^{-1}\theta)=\frac 1{\theta}\implies\sin(\sec^{-1}\theta)=\sqrt{1-\frac 1{\theta^2}}$$